# How to sync custom audio with video in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, video, avplayer, audiounit

I am trying to make a video player with custom audio effects. To perform an effect I've written an audio unit. To play video stream I use AVPlayer with muted sound. The problem is that audio and video are out of sync. And it gets awful when I pause and resume the playback.

Could you please suggest any ideas about how to sync the two things? Maybe use something else instead of AVPlayer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe your setup/approach more detailed. Where do you "stream" th video from? Where does the audio come from? How does the audio come to your Audio Unit? ...

Comment: @shallowThought Thank you for your reply, but I've already found the answer myself. It is posted below.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall answer my own question.
There is a thing called MTAudioProcessingTap. It allows for doing audio manipulation stuff just like an audio unit but inside AVPlayer.
There's a link for more details: https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/.=